# Permissions error when installing Ruby on OSX as per official docs, with rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, homebrew, rbenv

I am trying to install Rails on my OSX El Capitan v10.11.3, as per [these](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.11-el-capitan) official instructions. However, after installing ruby, I am getting the following issues with the rails installation:

> Unknown-88-63-df-a3-2e-e9:~ username$ gem install rails -v 4.2.4
>   ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
>       You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.

Even though I am using `rbenv` ? What can I do to workaround / fix this?

**EDIT:**  if I use `sudo` then I get:

> railties's executable "rails" conflicts with /usr/bin/rails
>
> ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM) Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/rails

Any ideas would be much appreciated. Many Thanks. Also, is there somewhere I can feed the resolution of this back into the rails docs community?

Comment: have you tried `sudo gem install rails -v 4.2.4`?

Comment: @martincarlin87 yes, then i get `railties's executable "rails" conflicts with /usr/bin/rails` followed by `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/rails`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install gems into the system ruby (i.e. the ruby that comes from Apple with OSX) don't do that.

Try:

```
rbenv versions
```

to list the versions of ruby you have.
Then pick one that is NOT system.

```
[16:55][d@phobos:~]$ rbenv versions
* system (set by /usr/local/var/rbenv/version)
  1.8.7-p357
  1.9.2-p290
  1.9.3-p392
  1.9.3-p448
  2.1.5
[16:55][d@phobos:~]$ rbenv local 2.1.5
[16:55][d@phobos:~]$ rbenv version
2.1.5 (set by /Users/d/.ruby-version)
[16:56][d@phobos:~]$
```

If you have nothing but system installed, install the rbenv build and install the ruby you want...

Read this carefully:
https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv
and this
https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build#readme

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `which ruby` check if it was pointing to `/Library/...`
2. Run `rbenv global x.y.z` to set current ruby version
3. **You may need to relaunch terminal**